# What are the limits of PHP's multi curl functions?

Tags: php, curl

Is there any limits in the max amounts of concurrent connections a multi curl session make?

I am using it to process batches of calls that I need to make to a API service, I just want to be careful that this does not effect the rest of my app.

A few queries, do curl sessions take up the amount of connections the apache server can serve? Is multi curl a ram or CPU hungry operation? I'm nit concerned about bandwidth because I have lots of it, a mighty fast host and only small amounts of data is being sent and received per request.

And I imagine it depends on server hardware / config...

But I can't seem to find what limits the amount of curl sessions on the documentation.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about limitations of the API you're calling.  People tend not to be too pleased with a single client opening dozens or hundreds of simultaneous clients.

Comment: Thats not a problem, I contacted my API service prior and they have a very very very impressive setup which can handle millions of requests... I get a limit of 10million requests per month... Will never get anywhere near that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP doesn't impose any limitations on the number of concurrent curl requests you can make. You might hit the maximum execution time or the memory limit though. It's also possible that your host limits the amount of concurrent connections you're allowed to make.

Comment: Nope, own server, self managed. Is there any article which has benchmark information on memory and CPU usage by multi curl sessions?